# Permissions in a Local Dev Environment (OS X)

Tags: permissions, apache, git, mac

I wanted to enable WordPress auto-updates to work without FTP, so I added: `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');` to my `wp-config.php`.

So in order to grant write privileges to WordPress's auto-updater, I ran `sudo chown -R _www:_www [wordpress-project-folder]`. I'm using _www instead of www-data, because I read that it's OS X's equivalent.

However, now anytime I modify a file with a Text Editor or commit changes with git within that wordpress folder, I need to `sudo`, which is slowing me down.

Is there a happy medium?

Answer (score 0):

It seems unorthodox but I added my user to the `_www` group:

`$ sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a 'whoami' -t user _www`

Finally, I gave write privileges to the group:

`$ sudo chmod -R g+w /path/to/dir`

That seems to work, but like I said seems like a weird solution to add my user to the `_www` group.

Maybe someone out there has a better solution.